# How can I Log out all the clients if signalR server(WPF) stopped accidentally?

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr

I am developing a chat application using signalR in WPF. There are two projects in it:

1) WPF Client

2) WPF Server

I want to disconnect and show login screen again at client side if server stops accidentally at any point of time.

Here is the code I have done on closing server window:

```
    private void ServerMainWindow_Closed(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SignalR != null)
        {
            SignalR.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I can handle database related stuff from here but how can I manage Clients?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Server: Send the custom message as "disconnect" in any one of the proxies.

In Client: Check for that custom message and redirect to login form because WPF signalR client doesnt not have onDisconnect built in function.

1. Initiating part on second window load:

   ```
   Get_App_Info_Proxy.On<string>("IO_Stay_Active", (responseHeartBeat) => OnReceiveDataHeartBeat(responseHeartBeat));
   ```
2. Invoking part on second window, just check on a regular interval based on the load the server capable to take, for my case its once for a minute.

   ```
   private void hbeatTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Get_App_Info_Proxy.Invoke("IO_Stay_Active");
   }
   ```
3. Receiving part on the second window:

   ```
   private void OnReceiveDataHeartBeat(string responseHeartBeat)
   {
        if (responseHeartBeat == "IO_101") // I would prefer custom code programmed in server
           {
                 Login loginform = new Login(); // redirecting first form
                 loginform.Show();
           }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the response, but I would like to have some other approach instead of sending custom message from server.

Comment: This is the best method. Signalr client won´t know server instance has shout down until 20 seconds later. Sending a message explicitly to clients will be fast.

Comment: @Arul can you please provide any sample code for this?

Comment: Edited again to include intiating part. :)